# Variable with name "name" returns only string

Tags: javascript, html, types

I spent way too much time on this, but here is what happened to me trying to fix a bug. I have to get value of an `<input type="text">` field with `id="name"`. Here is what I did:

```
var name = document.getElementById("name");
console.log(name.value);
```

I get the response `undefined`. I tried a few more stuff and then realized what just happened, with this piece of code for reference.

```
. . .
console.log(name);
console.log(typeof(name));
```

And I get the output

> "[object HTMLInputElement]"
>   "string" //why is this???

I only get the output as a string, with value above. I do not understand why it is returning a string instead of the vlaue *inside* the string. Here is where I solve the bug, I chose a different variable name and the code as follows:

```
var playerName = document.getElementById('name');
console.log(playerName);
console.log(typeof(playerName));
console.log('\n' + playerName.value);
```

and get the following output:

> <input type="text" placeholder="Enter name" id="name">
>   
>  object
>   
>  Hello //this is the real val entered
>   ...and this makes **absolutely no sense to me whatsoever.**.

Just for clarification: I did not run anything before this, I tried this after the problem in a new HTML file with a new `<script>` tag. I ran these pieces of code exactly like showed here, and I did it about 3 times and got the same result. If it helps my browser is: Google Chrome version `63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)`.

Thank you :-)

Comment: Create a working snippet demonstrating your issue.

Comment: .`window.name`.

Comment: And also for the output `<input type="text" placeholder="Enter name" id="name"> ` I used the chrome dev tools and don't think it will be like that otherwise though.

Comment: Ok @gurvinder372 please wait a few minutes.

Comment: This because `window.name` is a global variable - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_name.asp